# Get-Msoluser accepts a hardcoded string but not a variable for parameter UserPrincipalName

Tags: powershell

I'm going a little batty because I can't think of anything I'm doing wrong with this code snippet. I'm literally just trying to get a single user using `Get-MsolUser` using the parameter `-UserPrincipalName` in the following line:

`$usr = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $wantedUser`

I'm calling this code from within a function that originally had the `$wantedUser` variable as a parameter, but due to the issues I'm experiencing, I've tried to add it as a script variable, I've tried reassigning the parameter variable to a local function variable, but nothing works. I can put the raw user principal name in there like below:

`$usr = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "james@contoso.com"`

And it works... no problem. Queries and assigns the user information to the `$usr` variable as expected where the rest of my code logic works fine. I know I'm just probably stupidly looking over something simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Can someone please shed some light on what I might be doing wrong? I know it's passing the value in there to some extent because I get an exception saying the following:

```
Get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: "james@contoso.com".
At C:\locationWhereMyScriptIsLocated.ps1:19 char:12
+     $usr = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $wantedUser
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to `Get-MsolUser`, but from what I can tell, the error message
`Get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: "james@contoso.com".` suggests that the user name *mistakenly contains embedded `"` chars.* - that is, the *verbatim* value of `$wantedUser` may be `"james@contoso.com"` rather than the expected `james@contoso.com`.

Thus, as a quick fix, try:

```
$usr = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ($wantedUser -replace '"')
```

But it's worth investigating why these *embedded* `"` characters ended up in `$wantedUser` to begin with, and perhaps eliminate the problem at the source.

Comment: My god... you nailed it. I just don't really understand how I can pass it NOT containing the quotes if it's a string... I'm currently passing it to the function from a split string array, so I'm calling the function as `IsUserLicensed($lineArray[1])` which contains my UPN that I want to call `Get-MsolUser` with. Is there a better way I should be trying to pass string variables? Thank you so much... I knew it was just something dumb I was doing but I wasted so much time trying to wrack my brain on this.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @RedMageKnight. Passing a string variable is the right thing to do, you just need to make sure it contains just the UPN, nothing else. So you need to look at how you obtain the UPN from the string you're splitting.

Comment: Oh man... I'm an idiot. I know exactly why now - I'm pulling the data from a CSV and each of the elements of the line I'm pulling using Get-Content to read it has quotes around it. I realized this writing each line to host... you don't see the quotes in the actual CSV file, but in the output I see on the terminal shows it. Ugh... thank you again. I think it's time for a drink.